# Subset of $C[0,1]$ is nowhere dense

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $E_n$ be
$$E_n:=\{f\in C[0,1]\mid \text{exist } x_f\in[0,1] \text{ such that } |f(x)-f(x_f)|\leq n|x-x_f|,\, \forall x\in[0,1]\}.$$

How show that $E_n$ is nowhere dense, that is, $\mathrm{int}\  \overline{E_n} = \emptyset$?

Can someone help me?

Comment: This looks like an ingredient in the proof, via Baire Category, that there are continuous, nowhere differentiable functions. Perhaps [this paper](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/fs.pdf) will give you some ideas (see Lemma 16 and 17, in particular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked this thoroughly, but the following proof (informal and in outline form) should work:

First show that $E_n$ is closed: Assume $(f_i)$ is a sequence from $E_n$ that converges to $f$ in $C[0,1]$. For each $i$, choose $x_i\in[0,1]$ verifying  that $f_i\in E_n$. By compactness of $[0,1]$, we may assume $x_n$ converges to some $x\in[0,1]$. Show that $x$ verifies that $f\in E_n$.

Now, to show $E_n$ is nowhere dense, it suffices to show that given $f\in E_n$ and $\epsilon>0$,   there is an $g\notin F_n$ with $\Vert f -g\Vert<\epsilon$.

To do this, fix $f\in F_n$ and $\epsilon>0$.  First approximate $f$ with a piecewise linear function $\phi$ so that $\Vert \phi-f\Vert<\epsilon/2$. Choose $M$ so that $|\phi'|\le M$, where it exists. Now take a "sawtooth function", $\omega$, with $\Vert \omega\Vert<\epsilon/2$ such that $|\omega'|$ is large. Finally, take $g=\phi+\omega$. This function is piecewise linear and the slope of any "piece" is large in absolute value (as large as you like by choosing the correct sawtooth function). Let's take "large" to mean greater than $n$. It then will follow that given any $x\in[0,1]$, there is an $x_f$ (any point on the same "piece" as $x$ will do) that verifies that $g\notin F_n$.

And, of course, $\Vert f-g\Vert= \Vert f-(\phi+\omega)\Vert\le\Vert f-\phi\Vert +\Vert\omega\Vert<\epsilon.$

Comment: Since the closure of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense, you can omit the first part where you show $E_{n}$ is closed. On the other hand, knowing that these sets are closed does give you information about the Borel classification of their union, which can also be of interest.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Nowhere dense is defined as the closure of the set having empty interior. Of course a set can have empty interior while its closure doesn't (such as $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$). Or, am I missing something?

Comment: Oops, you're correct. However (trying to save myself ...), I believe if you begin with *it suffices to show that given* $f \in E_{n}$ with *it suffices to show that given* $f \in C[0,1],$ then the sets $E_n$ will be such that their closures have the desired "nowhere dense hole" property.

Comment: What’s $F_n$ here?